# Perl Filehandle Open Truncates the File

Tags: arrays, perl, truncate, filehandle

I am writing my first Perl program and it's a doozy. I'm happy to say that everything has been working for the most part, and searching this website has helped with most of my problems.

I am working with a large file composed of space separated values. I filter the file down to display only lines with a certain value in one of the columns, and output the filtered data to a new file. I then attempt to push all of the lines of that file into an array to use for looping. Here's some code:

```
my @orig_file_lines = <ORIG_FILE>;
open MAKE_NEW_FILE, '>', 'newfile.dat' or die "Couldn't open newfile.dat!";
&make_new_file(\@orig_file_lines);   ##Creates a new, filtered newfile.dat
open NEW, "newfile.dat" or die "Couldn't open newfile.dat!";
my @lines;
while(<NEW>){
 push(@lines,$_);
}
printf("%s\n", $lines[$#lines]);  ##Should print entirety of last line of newfile.dat
```

The problem is twofold: 1. $#lines = 24500 here when the newly created file (newfile.dat) actually has 24503 lines (so it should be 24502), 2. the printf statement returns a truncated line 24500, cutting off that line prematurely by about two columns.

Every other line, e.g. $lines[0-24499], will successfully print the entire line even when it is wider than $lines[24500], so the length of that particular line (they're all long) is not the problem. But it is almost as if the array has gotten too large somehow, since it cut off part of one line, and then the next two lines. If so, how do I combat this?

Comment: Well, I didn't show it here, but I actually printed it to a file, so it wasn't a terminal truncation. Also, $lines[24501] and $lines[24502] are still not accounted for.

Comment: If I print $#lines, I get 24500. There are 24503 lines in the file that I want. So printing $lines[0] gives me the entirety of the first line, $lines[24999] gives me the entirety of the 24500th line, but $lines[24500] gives me most, but not all, of the 24501st line. And $lines[24501] gives me an error because it is empty, but it should hold the 24502nd line. Ditto for $lines[24502].

Comment: How do you define 'lines'? This can happen when some are crlf terminated while some are lf terminated; and the way different tools interpret 'lines' based on this.

Comment: 'lines' is an array created from the filehandle in the 5-8 lines of the code above. Theoretically, each element of the array should hold an individual line, terminated by '\n'. I used the while loop there because my search for a solution stated that it was a better convention for large files. Whereas I was using @lines=<NEW> originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to close MAKE_NEW_FILE before opening the same file with NEW.

Some other points to look at:

- `&function` syntax is mostly deprecated because it bypasses prototype checking.
- I trust that you are using `use warnings;` and `use strict;`.
- I notice that you have a two-argument open and a three-argument `open`. Although both are legal they have different mindsets which makes using them together confusing to the programmer. I would stay with the three argument open because I think it is easier to understand (unless you are playing code golf)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 

You're right, I forgot to close MAKE_NEW_FILE, I will have to fix that. 

Is there another way to call the subroutine? I don't know of any other way than &subroutinecall();

Yes, they are both on! :)

Good point, I will change it to a 3-argument open.

Comment: The `&sub` syntax is frequently misused, as the OP did, but it's not deprecated since it serves a useful function: Calling a sub while ignoring its prototype.

Comment: It worked! I knew it must have been something silly. Note to self, close your filehandles! Thank you very much. Also, I had no idea you could call a subroutine without the '&'! I just read 'Learning Perl' and it told me to use it.

Comment: @ikegami : that is why i said mostly depreciated, because there are times that you want that syntax, but I would be willing to bet never in a first program.

Comment: @Malavin that recommendation was true for perl 4.

Comment: That's not what [deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) (or depreciated) means

Comment: @ikegami from the article you linked "Deprecation is a status applied to a computer software feature, characteristic, or practice indicating it should be avoided, typically because of it being superseded." in perl 4 and earlier all subroutine calls used &sub syntax. perl 5 introduced a new cleaner syntax which was designed to replace the earlier syntax, or to depreciate it. the redesign missed one advanced use case and later they added one other, but I was using the meaning defined in the article you referenced exactly.

Comment: There's no reason to avoid it, and it has not been superseded. You could do `\&foo->(@a)` instead of `&foo(@a)`, but why would you want to?

Comment: @ikegami, if you use `foo(@a)` it allows type checking, if you use `&foo(@a)` it does not. since I always wan type checking I do not use `&foo`. as for `\&foo->(@a)`  I've never had need of it but `&{$foo[$i]}(@a)` and `$foo[$i]->(@a)` are both very powerful constructs.

Comment: Re "*As for `\&foo->(@a)` I've never had need of it*", That's my point. While `\&foo->(@a)` can be used instead of `&foo(@a)`, `\&foo->(@a)` hasn't superceded `&foo(@a)` as the preferred way of bypassing prototypes, so `&foo(@a)` is not deprecated by the definition you quoted. You say "*&function syntax is mostly deprecated because it bypasses prototype checking*", but it's the exact opposite. `&function` is not even close to being deprecated because it's the supported way of bypassing prototypes.

Comment: @ikegami, you put words in my mouth that were never there,  as indeed &foo(@a) remains the preferred way of bypassing prototypes, and is not completely deprecated, only as I said mostly so. firstly in that the common case of prototypless functions it is no longer needed, secondly in the newer case of prototyped functions counterindicated, thirdly in the case of overriding prototypes where it is preferred the case the activity discouraged, leaving it of little value in most well written code absent those extreme cases of symbol table manipulation. cont . . .

Comment: If you find the overriding of prototypes common, perhaps you might ponder  why you find that so often useful and ask here or on a sister stack on better methods.

Comment: Re "*you put words in my mouth*", Yes, I corrected the spelling of "deprecated" in your answer, and fixed some formatting, that's all.

Comment: Re "*only as I said mostly so*", It's not deprecated at all. It's the preferred way to do what it does.

Comment: by the way cute trick edit, unupvote and downvote to get around the old vote rule.

Comment: @ikegami, Re: 'It's the preferred way to do what it does' exactly just what it does is not recommended any more ie deprecated. Re the edit that wasn't what I was talking about, think back to your rhetoric classes. Especially since we have been debating an esoteric side point of little direct relation to the problem of the question.